# How do i upload a file to my ftp at weebly.com?

Tags: c#, ftp

This is what they say about using the ftp:

```
http://www.ipage.com/controlpanel/FTP.bml
```

You can build your site using Web authoring tools, and then use an FTP program to upload the Web pages to your iPage account.

To access your account using an FTP client, you need to connect to ftp.newsxpressmedia.com with your FTP username and password.

This is the method i'm trying now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ScrollLabelTest
{
    class FtpFileUploader
    {
        static string ftpurl = "ftp://ftp.newsxpressmedia.com";
        static string filename = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static string ftpusername = "newsxpressmediacom";
        static string ftppassword = "*****";
        static string value;

        public static void test()
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpurl);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);

                // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
                StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
                byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
                sourceStream.Close();
                request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                requestStream.Close();

                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

                response.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                string t = err.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i'm getting exception on the line:

```
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

The exception:

```
The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command
```

The complete exception error message:

```
System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
       at ScrollLabelTest.FtpFileUploader.test() in e:\test\test\test\FtpFileUploader.cs:line 36
  InnerException:
```

Line 36 is:

```
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

Comment: Do you have objections to use a thirdy party open source library?

Comment: Steve i think not according to this: http://www.ipage.com/support/tutorials/index.bml?s=342&main=34

Comment: I have always found the standard FTP client cumbersome to work with. Instead this open source client is really easy to use http://netftp.codeplex.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(
    ftpUrl + "/" + Path.GetFileName(fileName));
```

You need to include the filename.